# bookdown problem knitting references at the end of section

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, bookdown

I've been writing books on bookdown for a long time. However, today, I just updated my R to R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) and Rstudio to 1.4.1106. And it messes my whole knitting results.

I used to have my references at the end of each section. And in the references page, every reference is spaced nicely so there is a line between two references. However, after the update, even though I changed my project option and global option so that my references would be at the end of each section, all of my references only show up on the references page, not at the end of each section. And now there is no space between two references on the reference page.

Is there any solution to this issue? I suspect this is because of my update, but I do not see any error; hence, I can't debug it.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of a RMD file that used to work but does not work anymore?

Comment: I think was my bad. But I just committed in my repositories. You can view it here: https://github.com/mikenguyen13/comm_theory And the book here: https://bookdown.org/mike/comm_theory/ I suspect if you build my book in the last R version, it should result in all the citations at the end of the section.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled into the same situation this morning having update R Studio to 1.4.1106 (R is 4.0.4). The R Studio update seemed to have made the `split_bib` flag in `_output.yml` inoperative. I think it's getting overridden in new visual settings.

In the R Studio preferences, under `R Markdown`, there is a `Visual` tab. Change the `Markdown | Write references at end of current` to `block`, `section' or 'document'. It makes no difference. References now only appear at the end of the document.

Comment: yep, I tried the same solution but did not prevail. I was hoping maybe somebody maintaining the bookdown package update their package.

Comment: As a workaround, you can run both versions side-by-side, or just download v 1.3.1093 and rebuild your book. The same project files produce different outputs.